# Client-side error monitoring that catches 404s and other script / resource errors?

Tags: error-handling, client-side

I've been looking into New Relic, BugSnag, and a few others, but no one seems to be catching 404 errors in their client-side monitoring. For example, say I have the following script tag in a given page:

```
<script src="//cdn.example.com/app.js1445291270"></script>
```

with the minor but critical typo of missing a `?` after `.js`.

This of course returns a 404 and the script never loads.

Are there any services that would catch client-side errors like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Bugsnag.  You can detect whether the status= 404, and use Bugsnag.notifyException() to send the error in.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[TrackJS error monitoring](https://trackjs.com/) supports this use case. Here is how to [add monitoring for resource loading failures](https://docs.trackjs.com/browser-agent/tips-and-tricks/monitor-resource-load-error/).